# Cassandra SSD / VHDX

Tags: cassandra

I'm about to create my first Cassandra cluster, starting from the first node :) But immediately I've ran into dilemma on how to implement drives to be used, so any word of advice will be appreciated. Here are musts:

- The node must run as Hyper-V (Win srv 2012 R2) VM
- I have 2 SSD 256 GB drives available for it
- Preferably Ubuntu 14.04 guest OS

My options:

1. Create dynamic stripped drive (basically software RAID0) in host OS (Win srv), and then create VHDX on top of it that will be used by guest Ubuntu;
2. No RAID, simply create two VHDX (one per SSD drive), and create guest Ubuntu that uses both VHDXs. Later within Ubuntu use one of the drives for logs and another for SSTables;
3. Do not create VHDX but connect (passthrough) physical SSDs to the newly created Ubuntu guest, then software RAID0 both SSD during Ubuntu setup process;
4. Similar with the previous but without software RAID0, and with assigning one drive for logs and other for SSTables

Which of the previous configuration would satisfy Cassandra best? Any resource (experience) about the differences in performances?

It is also important to know that the following **is NOT** important:

- SSD life time - If SSD will survive a year or 10 years is not important at all.
- Fault tolerance - I'm not afraid of zero fault tolerance of RAID0 configuration. Fault tolerance of the system will be achieved by using multiple nodes and the appropriate replication policy, so failure of one node is not important.

Also, I'll say that I would be happiest with the first option since it allows me to use my existing VM snapshot-based backup infrastructure, and maybe even add another VHDX on the same RAID0 that will be used by another, non-IO intensive VM.

Finally, when it comes to VHDX on top of SSD - dynamically expanding or fixed?

Many thanks!

I've forgot to say (not sure if important but...):

- The cluster should be write-optimized. Expected ingesting rate is 50,000 data points per second. Rare reads - probably no more than one per second.